# Flutter offset drop shadow around a transparent widget

Tags: flutter

I am unable to achieve this effect in Flutter web (rendered as HTML), whereby the requirement is to have a transparent container (card or otherwise) with an offset shadow:

[image: Transparent button with shadow]

Current code:

```
   Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.transparent,
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(myBtnRadius),
          boxShadow: [
            CustomBoxShadow(
              color: Colors.black87.withOpacity(myBtnShadowOpacity),
              blurRadius: 4,
              blurStyle: BlurStyle.outer,
              spreadRadius: -2,
              offset: const Offset(3, 5),
            ),
          ],
        ),
        child: ClipPath(
            clipper: ShapeBorderClipper(
                shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(myBtnRadius)))),
            child: _buildMyCard()),
      ),
```

CustomBoxShadow derived from code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51333105/flutter-add-box-shadow-to-a-transparent-container)

*_buildMyCard just returns a Card widget with elevation set to 0 and color transparent.*

Best result I can achieve is this:

[image]

Any ideas? Do I need to get more creative with some clipping / mask?

Answer (score 0):

Ultimately, when rendering a Flutter web app as HTML, the only way I could achieve this effect was to use a Stack widget with an html.DivElement using style.BoxShadow to create the shadow with cut-out effect.